# Cannot install JBoss AS, Wildfly, EAP tools in Eclipse Photon

Tags: eclipse, jboss, eclipse-plugin

I need to work with JBoss7.1 from Eclipse Photon. Trying to install JBoss Tools from Eclipse Marketplace with only "JBoss AS, Wildfly, EAP tools in Eclipse Photon" option selected, Eclipse tells me that I cannot install it due to some version conflict:

[image]

(I tried the various options suggested).
Is there some easy way to solve this (keeping Eclipse Photon)?

Comment: Looks like you *might* be trying to install the wrong version.  Need help?

Comment: Yes, if you know how to resolve this (an update site for a different JBoss Tools version, or whatever), please post it as an answer (also without full details).

Comment: Sorry, I missed the w/o full details part.  Let me know if it helps!

Answer (score 0):

I usually try and use the install links if available, marketplace has issues at times.  I also use Red Hat JBoss Development Studio as it's free and has a lot of nice features - I'm just not sure if it's a Photon build.

Anyway's, to install from a direct link navigate to this site [Photon Final 4.6.0](https://tools.jboss.org/downloads/jbosstools/photon/4.6.0.Final.html)

Then from the browser, drag the install Icon as shown in this screen shot into eclipse, you can drop it right on the editor pane.  It will require a restart of Eclipse.

[image: Browser to Eclipse IDE Drag and Drop Install]

The image is showing me left clicking on the install icon and then dragging it over to the eclipse editor pane.  Just release the left key over the editor. If for some reason that doesn't work.  You can try the other builds [here](https://tools.jboss.org/downloads/jbosstools/photon/index.html)

Comment: Thank you, but unfortunately the other plugin versions were for different Eclipse releases, and 4.6. does not work as I said. I think the "problem" was that I used EclipsePhoton "Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers" release, it contained some plugin/feature called TM Terminal as in the error message which conflicted with JBoss Tools. I uninstalled TM Terminal, and then could install the JBoss Tools 4.6 plugin.

Comment: Ah, glad you got it figured out!